# tabBar:didSelectItem and popToRootViewControllerAnimated

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` which contains several `UINavigationController`'s. When you click on a tab bar item I would like for it to navigation the user back to the root view controller for that navigation controller. I have the following code which works perfectly for an iPad2, iPhone4, iPhone5s, but not for an iPhone5. Does anyone have any idea as to why this might be?

*Update*: If I change the `afterDelay` to `.8` then it will work, but creates a flash as it changes view - not very desirable!

```
@implementation NavigationTabs

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    // Thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336907/how-to-reset-a-uinavigationview-to-display-the-root-controller-when-user-clicks#answer-21544648
    if ([self.selectedViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UINavigationController * view = (UINavigationController *)self.selectedViewController;
        [view performSelector:@selector(popToRootViewControllerAnimated:) withObject:nil afterDelay:.5];
    }
}

@end
```

---

*Update*: Working code below:

```
@interface NavigationTabs : UITabBarController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation NavigationTabs

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        [(UINavigationController *)viewController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the flashing by doing so,

Every time you navigate from tab A to tab B, after you call the

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:<index of tab>];
```

on tabBar, call the `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` on tab A.

That way once you navigate back to Tab A you don't have to pop it to the root viewController it will be at the root already.

If you are not changing the tabs by code, then you can register to get delegate methods from `UITabBarControllerDelegate`

you can implement the

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

To get notification on what viewController has been pressed

Comment: That's a good idea. However, I can't seem to find a function named `changeTab` or one similar in `UITabBarController`?

Comment: Thanks for that, however I am not changing the tab programatically - the user is clicking it on the tab bar.

Comment: then you can register for delegate methods, i have edited my answer :)

Comment: Thanks, @YuviGr, that seems to have solved the issue!

Comment: Glad to help my friend!